Indentation difference in code block of Markdown Preview Enhanced
I found that the indentation in code block is different between editor (VS Code) and Markdown Preview Enhanced (so does the highlighting):

Would there be a way of adjusting the indentation to the same as in the editor's?

are you using tabs or space? if spaces it's probably just a difference in the fonts.

@mb21 I tried tab and space*4, it is the same.... Let me try to change the font

@mb21 no place to change the font of preview enhanced

On the image on the right, the code block font doesn't seem to be monospace. Which is bad.

@mb21 yep, but I cannot find where to change the font  of the code block of markdown preview enhanced

@mb21 done, change the code block's font need to use customize css (style. Less file) type in the following
html body code {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;
}


@Shore Sounds like an answer :) Please post it. (Yes, you can answer your own question.)

@Shore BTW, I just added a link to the extension for reference, but correct me if it's the wrong one.

Just change the font of markdown preview enhanced code block by the following steps:

cmd+shift+p
type in markdown preview enhanced: customize css
it will open a file and add
html body code {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace;
}

to the last of it, looks like this:


